# Calling a method of a second Java class in Android

Tags: android, class, methods

Ok so I have dumbed this down to the bare minimum to resolve and issue I am having.

I have two classes. The second class extends the first and has a simple toast message. I call the second class toast method from the oncreate of the first to try and display the toast. No errors are reported in the program and it compiles. When it runs it immediately crashes nothing ever appears. If I remove the call to the second class and put the toaster in the first class it works so I know the toaster is correct.

First class

```
package com.example.testingclasses;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class FirstClass extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_class);

        SecondClass toaster = new SecondClass();
        toaster.toastSC();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_class, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

second class

```
package com.example.testingclasses;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

    public void toastSC(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Toast from second class";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
    }
}
```

let me know if a log cat is needed but I'm sure this is a code issue. This is referenced here and several sites but I simply cannot get it to work. Oh and did a simple one like this but with a print statement in Java and ran it and all the calls worked so this is something here in Android as far as I can tell and I am simply not getting it.

thanks

Comment: 1. never call new operator on Activity derived class 2.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding (i really don't know where is your problem, why SecondClass extends FirstClass ? are you familiar with OOP? there is no need for this ..) you should build static helper class with static method with Context as parameter ...

Comment: I extended the first class from the second because I seen that in several answers on here. It did not help but I left it because removing it killed the whole process. I have since moved on as I no longer required to use this. I am studying up on this however and think I found my error.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is bad. Why don't you just do the following?

```
public class SecondClass {

    public void toastSC(Context context) {
        CharSequence text = "Toast from second class";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

and call it from your Activity class

```
new SecondClass().toastSC(this);
```

Comment: I think creating SecondClass, it means creating activity, will cause same problem

Comment: @Adem, You're right, it was a silly mistake which ruined the whole point I wanted to make. Fixed now.

Comment: That worked and I'll try it on my main program. Funny though as no-one ever showed this way... even on here as what I posted was the way others said to do it directly from this site on other similar questions. Once I run it I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: as i wrote ... extending is unnecessary here ... also he can make this **method static** and use without SecondClass instance ... `SecondClass.toastSC(this)`

Comment: This won't work from my program. The second class returns a TextView settext and that is not working. It does a lot. So for now I'll just keep that code in the main class and dup it out till I have time to sort it all out.

Comment: @reddragon72, In case you've found this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: It is helpful for the toaster but I cannot figure out how to use that in my main code. I may post it up later. +1 here because I do not have enough rep points yet to plus anything.

Answer (score -1):

you should not create second activity. use `SecondClass` in your manifest and it will create instance from `SecondClass` and then use `this` instance to call function

```
SecondClass toaster = (SecondClass)this;
toaster.toastSC();
```

Comment: do not use this solution ... it is bad ... you don't need extending at all

Comment: why you dont need to extend. it is already extended to Activity, and it can be extended some other class too.

Comment: unnecessary upcasting is bad 'key ... if you are in SecondClass instance there is no need to cast this to SecondClass ... you can simply call toastSC ... it you are in FirstClass instance there is no assurance that you are inside SecondClass (so casting this to SecondClass will fail) ...

Comment: why it is bad ? it is a feature of Java. so there is nothing to use it unless you know what you are doing